# Bing maps for iPhoneSDK

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, bing-maps, bing-api

Does anyone know how to create simple iPhone app using bing maps?

Comment: I am interested in this as well.

Answer (score 4):

The Bing Mobile/Bing Maps team released a new Bing Maps iOS SDK for iPhone and iPad in early May 2011.  You can download the SDK [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6e01a102-49ed-409e-b384-0b67521fb612) and read about the details in this [blog post](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2011/05/05/new-bing-maps-ios-sdk.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would start by reading their [API](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/) and figure out which services to use

Answer (score 0):

You may also find that the Bing Maps V7 AJAX control used with PhoneGap gives you a lot more power. Using this approach you get the full power of Bing Maps and the ability to then re-use your application accorss not just iPhone and iPad, but other mobile devices as well.