# How to integrate Microsoft Bing Map Navigation functionality to iPhone application?

Tags: ios, iphone, dictionary, navigation, bing-maps

I have studied about Microsoft Bing Map Navigation. There is iOS support and sdk available at http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/mobile.aspx

Can anyone guide me how to use this in my application? My requirement is to create an application having functionality like Google Navigator does, displaying direction using GPS.

Comment: please look around before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519057/bing-map-integration-into-iphone-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933841/bing-maps-for-iphonesdk

Comment: plus no one can code for you, so youll have to guide yourself how to use it :)

Comment: Thanks xs2bush, that information really helps me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this project might be a good starting point for what you are looking for:
https://github.com/route-me/route-me

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot** create a turn-by-turn navigation product using the Bing Maps (or Google Maps) SDK. You can use it to generate directions but cannot present any sort of alert for upcoming turns. From the TOU at http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html:

> Restrictions on your use: We do have some restrictions on your use of the service. You may not:
>
> ...
>
> present or alert an end user to individual maneuvers of a route in any way that is synchronized with the end-user’s sensor-based position along the route, (e.g. “real-time” navigation);
>
> ...