# Rendering custom indoor maps

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, user-interface, maps

I wonder what's the best approach to render custom indoor map. This app should let users to zoom in/out and track some basic path (maps in 2D).
What you think to render the map in Cocoa Drawing, or maybe is it possible to do it with MapKitView ?

Comment: Not  sure, but hope this one gives you a base-start. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7471790/775896 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943195/how-to-integrate-microsoft-bing-map-navigation-functionality-to-iphone-applictio
https://github.com/route-me/route-me

Comment: what about rendering custom maps, not only geo localised

Comment: Do you have any reference links?